# How do I run a python file i've already made on another pc on my raspberry pi?

Tags: raspbian, python

I've already written a python program, I have no idea how to usb mount so would it be easier putting it on my microsd card used to boot my pi up?
My pi is using raspbian-jessie-lite and i don't understand any commands in great depth. So all I want to do is run a python file off my raspberry pi.. please help.

Comment: Can't you network the Pi?

Comment: I'm using it with putty to control it

Comment: Perhaps putty has a command to copy a file similar to the sftp command used by the ssh suite?

Comment: This Q&A discusses the PuTTY file transfer tools.  https://superuser.com/questions/338075/how-do-i-transfer-a-file-to-my-server-using-putty  But FileZilla is easier to use.

Comment: If you intend to run your program as a command you will want to use the "which python" command to get the string for the shebang (#!) for the first line of the file.  Then you can use "chmod +x <filename>" to make it executable.  It does not need the .py extension when you do it this way.

Comment: And no, you do not want to try to just put it on the micro SD card.  It is easier to mount the USB.  Plug in the USB drive, then use file manager look in the /media/pi directory to find it.  Then you can copy it to your home directory (make a python subdirectory for this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

connect via **sftp**(FileZilla) to your rasppberry pi and just upload a file. then connect to the raspberry via ssh and `cd` to the path where you uploaded your file and run command `python YourFile.py`